# selenium geolocation permisson on linux

Tags: linux, selenium, geolocation

Recently I am using selenium to write a program that run on Linux(ubuntu 20.04).A visit to a web page, it prompts me it needs geolocation permission.In the code, I've given it the geolocation permission,

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",{"profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1})
```

and I've set my location:

```
Map_coordinates = dict({
        "latitude": latitude,
        "longitude": longitude,
        "accuracy": 98
    })
    self.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", Map_coordinates)
```

but apparently didn't work.Why?What should I do?(The code is can be used on Windows, no longer warrant permissions)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it(Excuse my poor English).
On Linux, you **must** use a visual interface.
I added this code to the program:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 940))  
display.start()
```

And I comment the code `chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')`.

And before that, I installed the ubuntu-desktop for my ubuntu-20.04. I don't know if ubuntu-desktop is necessary. But happily, I made it.